# How to add value from the title to the value of the class to the same element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, title

How to add value from the title to the value of the class to the same element with jQuery?

For Example, I will add word "new1" to title name for picture of 1.jpg.
And then in class of picture 1.jpg it will get class of "new1" by jQuery.

```js
<script> 
    $( document ).ready(function() {
 
 $("[title*='animotion']").addClass('new1',function(){
    $(this).parent().css('overflow','visible'); 
    str=$(this).attr("title");
    str=str.replace('animotion ','');
    return str}).removeAttr('title');

    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So if I add "animotion new23" I have in class tag only new1. So how can I edit this code that new 23 will be in class?

=======================================================================
NEW Question.
So after that how to add css class to new1 to style.css?

Comment: What have you tried so far.? edit your question and post the code for us to help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use title value to add classes, than you can do it simply this way:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 $("[title*='animotion']").addClass(function(){
  $(this).parent().css('overflow','visible'); 
  return $(this).attr('title');
 }).removeAttr('title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" title="animotion newClass new1" /></p>
```

jQuery [addClass method](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) accepts class name(s) or a function. In both cases the value must be a string that contains:

> One or more space-separated classes to be added to the class attribute
>   of each matched element.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("[title*='animotion']").addClass(function(){
        // add the string that you want to applear and concatenate it with the title attribute of the object and return it as a parameter to addClass;
        return 'new1'+$(this).attr('title');
   });
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, `.addClass()` takes **either** a string or a function, not both. Try chaining calls of `.addClass()`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("[title*='animotion']").addClass('new1').addClass(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('overflow','visible'); 
    str=$(this).attr("title");
    str=str.replace('animotion ','');
    return str}).removeAttr('title');

});
```